# Find out if id equals visible or hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why this passes my if condition when I hide my Div element above. I'm trying to figure out a way to write if div id equals visible then alert the user "content visible". If my div id equals hidden then alert the user "content hidden"

```js
//document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "visible";

var status = document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility;


if($("#myDiv").is(":visible") == true){
    alert("visible JQuery");
}

if (document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility === "hidden")
{
   alert("visible JS");
}

alert(status);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
```

Comment: In [the jQuery docs about the `:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/): _Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout._ That's why the jQuery condition passes. You can still do this: `if($("#myDiv").css("visibility") !== "hidden")`. Your JS condition passes too, because you check that the visibility **is** `hidden`. Change `===` to `!==`.

Answer (score 1):

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

[jQuery :visible](http://Elements%20with%20visibility:%20hidden%20or%20opacity:%200%20are%20considered%20visible,%20since%20they%20still%20consume%20space%20in%20the%20layout.)

The `:visible` selector will only work for the attribute `display`.

What you can do is:

```
if ($("#myDiv").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
    // do something when hidden ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";

if($("#myDiv").css("visibility") !== "hidden") {
  alert("visible JQuery");
}

if (document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility === "hidden") {
   alert("hidden JS");
}
```

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/foozie3moons/pen/OxgomO

**EDIT**
Updated my response as if you were not setting visibility to visible.

Comment: This is small enough that it would be better as a stack-snippet so one could run it right here (like the OP used in the question) instead of a codepen.

Answer (score 0):

visibility = 'hidden' still takes up space in the browser, and so jQuery reports as ":visible".  If you did style.display = 'none', your jQuery visible check wouldn't fire.